# Why is $\log\left(\frac{2a+2b+3}{2a+2b+1}\right)>\frac{1}{a+b+1}$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> Why is $\log\left(\frac{2a+2b+3}{2a+2b+1}\right)>\frac{1}{a+b+1}$ ? with $a,b\ge 0$

If this is true (I don't know whether it is true, just inserted some values in wolfram alpha) then I can show that $\frac{1}{a+b+1}<\int_{a}^{a+1}\int_{b}^{b+1}\frac{1}{x+y}dxdy$

Is it possible to see it from Taylor ?

Comment: what kind of numbers are $$a,b,c$$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{a+b+1/2}^{a+b+3/2}\frac{dx}{x}=\log(\frac{2a+2b+3}{2a+2b+1})>\frac{1}{a+b+1}$$

This is true because $1/x$ is a strictly convex function. More generally, for  any strictly convex $f$, we actually have:

$$\frac{1}{x_2-x_1}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)\,dx > f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\frac{2a+2a+3}{2a+2b+1} = 1+ \frac{2}{2a+2b+1} = 1+\frac{1}{a+b+1/2}.$$

The Maclauren series for $\log(1-x)=-x-x^2/2-x^3/3-\cdots.$  So your left side

$$=\log\left(1-\frac{-1}{a+b+1/2}\right)  = \frac{1}{a+b+1/2} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a+b+1/2}\right)^2+\cdots . $$

The series is alternating so the above is

$$> \frac{1}{a+b+1/2}>\frac{1}{a+b+1}.$$

Comment: Possibly worth adding that you can save yourself a step on the inequality if you compare to the series expansion for $\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ instead.

Comment: This is not true, by alternating series, $\log(\dots)$ is smaller than $\frac{1}{a+b+1/2}$ and greater than $\frac{1}{a+b+1/2}-\frac 12\left(\frac{1}{a+b+1/2}\right)^2$

Comment: @user314  I think you're right, but I'm off to an event just now.  Stand by.

Answer (score 2):

Set $a+b+1=1/c$, so
$$
\frac{2a+2b+3}{2a+2b+1}=
\frac{\frac{2}{c}+1}{\frac{2}{c}-1}=\frac{2+c}{2-c}
$$
and the inequality is
$$
\log\frac{2+c}{2-c}>c
$$
for $0<c\le1$.

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\log(2+x)-\log(2-x)-x
$$
defined over $[0,1]$. Then $f(0)=0$ and
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{2+x}+\frac{1}{2-x}-1=\frac{x^2}{4-x^2}>0
$$
over the interval $(0,1)$. So the function is increasing.